# "Geld sparen" oder "zurücklegen"

Tags: meaning, difference, verb

What is the difference between *Geld sparen* and *Geld zurücklegen*?

Don't they both mean save money? When do you use what?

Comment: It's pretty much like the English _save_ vs. _put by_: when do you use what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Geld zurücklegen** or **Geld zur Seite legen** would specifically refer to putting money aside, whether it's under a matress or in a bank.

Example

> Ich lege für mein Alter Geld zurück.

Translation

> I put money aside for my old age.

Or

> Ich lege jeden Tag Geld zur Seite, damit ich mir ein neues Auto kaufen
>   kann.

Translation

> I put money aside every day, so I can buy a new car.

**Geld sparen** has that connotation, but also can simply mean that you saved money by spending less, such as shopping somewhere cheaper.

As in the old proverb

> Spare [Geld] in der Zeit, dann hast du in der Not.

Translation

> Save [money] in times when you can, so you have it when times are
>   rough.

But also in this sense

> Wenn ich bei Aldi einkaufe, dann spare ich Geld.

Translation

> When I shop at Aldi, I save money.

Answer (score 3):

There is a subtle difference.

**(Geld) sparen** means that you create an extra bank account or put the money under your pillow (for example to buy something expensive in the future).

> Wir sparen für ein neues Auto.

*Also*, **sparen** means that you have a possibility to spend less money on something.

> Dank dem Sonderangebot konnten wir 100€ sparen, weil das Fahrrad nur 899 € gekostet hat.

**Geld zurücklegen** has a similar meaning to the first meaning of **sparen**, but it implies *often*, that you save money without any specific goal; mostly to have something on the side (***auf der hohen Kante***) if your financial situation gets worse in the future. But it *can* mean saving money for a goal.
So, this is quite the same meaning as *sparen* (1st meaning).

> Wir haben ein wenig Geld zurückgelegt (=*auf die Hohe Kante gelegt*), für den Fall, dass wir das Land verlassen müssen.
>
> Wir verdienen gut und sparen.
>
> Deutsche sind Sparer. Sie geben nicht viel aus, sie legen lieber etwas zurück.
>
> Wir haben bereits 6000€ für ein neues Auto zurückgelegt.

Another point is that **sparen** subliminally implies a specific lifestyle (of being ***sparsam***). If you have a very good salary, you don't have to **sparen**, but you can still **zurücklegen** something.

> Ich und mein Mann führen eine erfolgreiche Firma. Obwohl wir nicht besonders sparen, konnten wir bereits eine schöne Summe für ein Haus zurücklegen.

Comment: Your first example sentence for *Geld zurücklegen* exactly contradicts  the "without any specific goal" part of the explanation - I would consider "Für den Fall, dass wir das Land verlassen müssen" a "specific goal".

Comment: I have to disagree. A specific goal would be a new car, a journey or something like that. In my example there is a "case", which may or may not occur, and the people just want to feel safe. That's the point.

Comment: I think the main point is your assumption *Geld zurücklegen* == *auf die hohe Kante legen* - That is not the same thing. You can "Geld zurücklegen für ein neues Auto" (That definitely is a specific goal). "Auf die hohe Kante legen", however, has, as you rightly say, no specific goal other than owning the money for whatever purpose you might come across in future.

Comment: In this case you're right, I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a slight difference between the two expressions:

*Geld sparen*

Is used for different purposes:

- Put money in the piggy bank to save it for later, or maybe for a dedicated purpose.

> Mein Bruder spart auf ein neues Auto

- When deciding between two alternative things to buy, buy the cheaper (longer lasting, less consuming, or generally, more cost-effective,...) thing. In this case, there is no evidence what you *actually do* with the money you don't spend - You could simply go to the next shelf and buy something else with it.

> Sparen Sie bares Geld - Kaufen Sie Woopy im 10er-Pack!

*Geld zurücklegen*

Only has the former meaning, there is always some "grand purpose" behind the saving (not necessarily excluding the "grand purpose" of just owning the money):

> Wir legen heute schon jeden Monat Geld für unsere Altersversorgung zurück

Answer (score 1):

*Geld sparen* is somewhat redundant, since *sparen* alone already means to save money. It is only to due the inflationary use in advertisements (where it frequently indicates just spending a [very little] bit less), that additional clarification is useful.

*Geld zurücklegen* already implies putting the money into a separate bank account or just in an envelope, so it won't be spent easily.

Comment: On the assumed redundancy of "Geld sparen": How about "Benzin sparen", then?

Comment: @tofro If one says *Ich habe gespart*, what would you assume that has been saved?

Comment: Gegenfrage: "Ich habe mir den neuen Huyabasa gekauft. Mit dem spare ich 2l auf 100km". *Context* and *redundancy* is not the same thing. *Ich habe gespart* could also very well be an answer to "WIe bist du, ohne zu tanken, von München bis nach Hamburg gekommen"

Comment: I do agree, though, that *in the absence of any context* "sparen" is most probably about money.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion as a native speaker, "Geld sparen" refers to saving money in general maybe without a special purpose. I would always use "Zurücklegen" with something specific in mind why I put this money aside. So, the difference is not the location where you put it, but why you put it there.